# Anonymous functions in Javascript - why the indirection?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I am going through the freecodecamp Javascript bootcamp. While I know the concept of anonymous functions and have extensively used them in C++, I am not able to understand the difference between the following two cases in Javascript:

**Case A - This is how I first wrote an anonymous func in Javascript**

```
const stats = {
  max: 56.78,
  min: -0.75
};

const half = (stats) => {
             return (stats.max + stats.min) / 2.0;
};

console.log(half(stats))
```

**Case B - Freecodecamp has been using the following more extensively**

```
const stats = {
  max: 56.78,
  min: -0.75
};

const half = (function() {
         return function half(stats) {
             return (stats.max + stats.min) / 2.0;
   };
})();

console.log(half(stats))
```

At first I thought this had something to do with recursion but that doesn't look like being the case.

I have tried both and both return the same result and both have the same call signature. Is there something additional about **Case B** or any use case where this might be required? Overall, how would I read this function? Like, for **Case A**, I could simply say that *half is a function that takes stats as an input and returns some value*

Comment: That indeed looks uselessly redundant.

Comment: The second one is an IIFE used just to create the function. It doesn’t change the resulting function.

Comment: Case B is return a function and execute it immediately with IIFE

Comment: Wanted to make sure that apart from the self-executing purpose, if there was anything else I was missing. Thanks for clarifying the details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case B function is known as self-invoking/excuting function.

Here it is serving no purpose.
[self executing function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592396/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-self-executing-function-in-javascript)